# Crystal reports at android

Tags: android, eclipse, crystal-reports, report

Is there any way to load a crystal report (.rpt) file to android application with eclipse?

Comment: Is this of use? http://androidapp.lisisoft.com/android-apps/crystal-reports-viewer.html

Comment: Did you get any Solution for this ?

Comment: No. Unfortunately not. I created custom html reports.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look [here](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalreports-eclipse/index.epx)?

> With SAP Crystal Reports, version for Eclipse, you can benefit from
>   the following:
>
> - Support for SAP Crystal Reports features such as embedded Flash, parameter panel, and sort controls
> - Flash-based prompting user interface that supports dynamic, cascading prompts at runtime for Web apps
> - Comprehensive SDK that enables complete report creation and modification with Java code
> - Ability to easily embed the Java runtime engine into thick and thin client applications
> - Access Java classes (POJOs) as a data source for tight integration to your applications
> - New editable preview in the Eclipse report design tool for improved productivity
> - Support for all major browsers and operating systems
> - Simpler licensing for combined use with SAP Crystal Reports

I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: It is what I look for. I installed it (copied files to eclipse\plugins and eclipse\features) and now ecliplse has a crystal perspective where you can create report. But I can not run the report in my code. I found this site ( http://ravimuthusubramanian.sys-con.com/node/1118330/mobile ) that has an example but ReportClientDocument is not recognized. I tried to import something like com.crys.... or com.businessonj... but nothing.....